# How to change child component props using computed property inside parent component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I've a problem with updating the props use computed property from the parent component,

here is the script from the child component

```
var bgChild = {
  name: 'bg-image',
  props: {
    bgBoolean: {
     type: Boolean,
     required: true,
    },
    mb: {
     type: String,
     default: '../images/images.png'
    },
    dp: {
     type: String,
     default: '../images/imagesDp.png'
    }
  }
}
```

inside my parent component

```
const bgParent = Vue.extend {
  template: '#parent',
  components: {
    'bg-child': bgChild
  },
}
```

and inside the the parent markup

```
<template id="parent">
  <div class="parent-div>
    <bg-child :src="bg-boolean ? md : dp"></bg-child>
  </div>
</template>
```

The question is how I change the value of `bgBoolean` inside the parent component use computed property? Because in the parent component I want to use a media query function to show and hide the image. I'll appreciate the help.

Comment: `the parent markup` - does that even work?

Comment: yes it is work, it display the image on `mb` props because the default is set to be `true`

Comment: so, what's `md`?

Comment: as you can see, `md` is a props from childComponent that linking a image as default property

Comment: my bad, it should be `mb` not `md`

Comment: so, `bg-boolean ? md : dp` works? - considering the PARENT has no data named `bg`, `boolean`, (yes, that's right, that's two different things, `bg-boolean` is `bg` minus `boolean`) ... `md`, or `dp` - and the child has no prop called `src` I can't see that line is doing anything except spitting out errors in the dev version of vuejs

Comment: but it is works, when I change the bgBoolean value to ```false``` the image is also update to ```dp```

Comment: sure, when you change the default in the child ... you have no control over it in the parent, since you're not doing anything there that effects it

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: should I make a props with the same name in the parent component

Comment: no, you don't need props with the same name ... you just need to use props properly :p - and without seeing what `src` in the child is used for, it's a bit difficult to help